# Is there a way I can check for null object in AddRange() method linq statement?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check in the below code if no match is found it should not throw object reference null error.

```
 itm.lstCustomziation.AddRange(
     (from xx in db.vw_DressingCustomization
      where xx.CatID == itm.HeaderName.Value && xx.ProductID == itm.ProductID
      select new itmCustomization()
      {
          catId = (int)xx.CatID,
          custType = customizationType.Dressing,
          isCustomziationDisplay = xx.IsDefaultDisplay,
          isFixLimit = (bool)xx.isDefaultLimit,
          maxLimit = (short)xx.DefaultFreeCount,
          itmName = xx.Description,
          isItemDefault = xx.IsDefaultDisplay,
          price = (double)xx.MainPrice,
          proId = (int)xx.ProductID
      }).ToList<itmCustomization>());
```

Comment: Actually `ToList()` should not return null. If sequence is empty it returns empty list.

Comment: from xx in db.vw_DressingCustomization
      where xx.CatID == itm.HeaderName.Value && xx.ProductID == itm.ProductID here it fails..

Comment: Is it Linq to SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: "xx.CatID == itm.HeaderName.Value" I guess problem is here,

Comment: here it fails xx.ProductID == itm.ProductID

Answer (score 0):

You should break it into multiple steps. First execute the query and get the results. Then you should check for null/count and based on that check call the add range method. It would be more readable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add check whether your nullable `itm.HeaderName` really has value before accessing that value:

```
 where itm.HeaderName.HasValue &&  // check if value exists
       xx.CatID == itm.HeaderName.Value && // otherwise here is the problem
       xx.ProductID == itm.ProductID
```

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet sorry, didn't get you. Where it fails now and what error you have?

Comment: it fails at productID

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet it throws `NotImplementedException`?

Comment: if i get more than 1 values for the above condition does it fails for that reason?

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet no, if there will be more than 1 items, then you will have list with all of them (btw I believe you don't need `ToList()` here, because `AddRange` accepts `IEnumerable`

Comment: i get this error ..Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45286/discussion-between-novicetodotnet-and-sergey-berezovskiy)